# calculating counts and percentages of a variable

Tags: r, count, tidyverse, percentage

I am trying to create a count of the number of observations and extract percentages from those counts.

I have data that looks like this:

```
UserID              substance_use                     
43124                       0 
43124                       1
43124                       0 
43124                       0
43124                       1
215                         1
215                         1
```

I want a count of the total observations of substance use like this:

```
UserID             substance_use                                 count  
43124                       0                                        5
43124                       1                                        5
43124                       0                                        5
43124                       0                                        5
43124                       1                                        5
215                         1                                        2
215                         1                                        2
```

And then, I want the % of visits that participants said yes and no, like this:

```
UserID      substance_use      count      percent_yes       percent_no
43124        0                  5            40%               60%
43124        1                  5            40%               60%
43124        0                  5            40%               60%
43124        0                  5            40%               60%         
43124        1                  5            40%              0%  
215          1                  2            100%              0
215          1                  2            100%              0%
```

I tried using the count function for the first part, but it's not taking into account the 0's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check your example. It doesn‘t make sense to me that the first ID gets count 4 and the second one 3. also pleaee provide an reproducible example with dput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `add_count` to create the 'count' column and then get the `mean` of the binary column by group to return the `percent_yes` and subtract 100 from the percent_yes to return `percent_no`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  add_count(UserID, name = 'count') %>%
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  mutate(percent_yes = 100 * mean(substance_use), 
       percent_no = 100 - percent_yes) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  UserID substance_use count percent_yes percent_no
   <int>         <int> <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1  43124             0     5          40         60
2  43124             1     5          40         60
3  43124             0     5          40         60
4  43124             0     5          40         60
5  43124             1     5          40         60
6    215             1     2         100          0
7    215             1     2         100          0
```

NOTE: Here, we assumed no missing values in 'substance_use' column

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(43124L, 43124L, 43124L, 43124L, 43124L, 
215L, 215L), substance_use = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. You were correct. It should have been 5.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the aggregated (!) info in each row or rather want to summarize per ID, in which case you can do:
(using the same df1 data as provided in akrun‘s answer)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
df1 %>%
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  summarize(count = n(),
            percent_yes = percent(sum(substance_use == 1)/count),
            percent_no = percent(sum(substance_use == 0)/count))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  UserID count percent_yes percent_no
   <int> <int> <chr>       <chr>     
1    215     2 100%        0%        
2  43124     5 40%         60%
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(UserID = c(43124, 43124, 43124, 43124, 43124, 
215, 215), substance_use = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
  mutate(count = ave(UserID, UserID, FUN = length),
    percent_yes = ave(substance_use, UserID, FUN = \(x) 100*sum(x)/length(x)),
    percent_no = 100 - percent_yes)

#>   UserID substance_use count percent_yes percent_no
#> 1  43124             0     5          40         60
#> 2  43124             1     5          40         60
#> 3  43124             0     5          40         60
#> 4  43124             0     5          40         60
#> 5  43124             1     5          40         60
#> 6    215             1     2         100          0
#> 7    215             1     2         100          0
```